# Copy first 25 rows from visible rows after filter using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm stuck with something in one of the projects.

How do I copy first 25 rows from all the visible rows after I've applied filter on one of the columns. Currently it is copying all the visible range.

```
With xlSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With xlApp.Worksheets("source").Range("A1:G1000")
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="x1"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With
End With
```

Then I change the filter to x2 and want to copy first 25 rows for that filter and so on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After the filter has been applied, the macro will copy the first 25 rows from *Sheet1* to *Sheet2 (excluding the header row)*

```
Sub dural()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    i = 1
    For j = 2 To Rows.Count
        If sh1.Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            sh1.Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Copy sh2.Cells(i, 1)
            i = i + 1
            If i = 26 Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I want to copy the data from excel to powerpoint, so I cannot copy and paste row by row. Thus I just want to select first 25 visible rows in case visible rows exceed 25 OR all the visible rows in case it is less then 25.

Comment: Do you want to capture an embedded Excel Object in PowerPoint or just put a picture in a PowerPoint slide??

Comment: Just paste it as a picture